# Update NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-12.04, nvidia-graphics-card

I have installed `nvidia-current` drivers through terminal. Nevertheless, the version provided by Ubuntu repository is 290.50, and I'd like to install the new Nvidia release (304.50). What should I do to properly update the drivers? Should I remove the current installation and afterwards install the new driver?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/nvidia-current/304.43-0ubuntu5